# oracle sql tuning

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to tune below query on a fact table while used in informatica mapping

```
select * from TFREVENUE
where revenue_close_dt_yearmonth > '2009/01'
  and revenue_flag = 'No'
  and revenue_update_date > (sysdate - 3)
```

There are no indexes defined on the filter columns such as `revenue_close_dt_yearmonth`, `revenue_flag`, or `revenue_update_date`.  Are there any steps i need to follow so that decrease bottleneck when i use this query in ETL mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no indexes defined, defining an index would generally be a first step assuming the table is not partitioned.  A composite index on the three columns you're filtering on would probably improve the performance of the query.